# var в цикле JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Код:

```
   function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
        var old = array[i];
        array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
        array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
      }
      return array;
    }
```

Значит ли это, что каждую итерацию цикла создается новая переменная old?
После С/С++ я бы предпочел написать так:

```
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  var old;
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}
```

Как правильнее?

Comment: Заменить `var` на `let` и внести внутрь цикла. Да и в C/C++ лучше внести внутрь цикла.

Comment: И в JS можно без 3ей переменной через деструктуризацию: for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
        [array[i], array[array.length - 1 - i]] = [array[array.length - 1 - i], array[i]]
      }

Comment: То есть каждую итерацию цикла я буду создавать новую переменную с таким же именем? А зачем в С то хоть такое делать ?

Comment: Если вы используете `var`, то неважно, где именно вы объявите переменную, она "всплывёт" в начало функции. Т.е. использовать переменную `old` вы можете **до** объявления (даже до цикла `for`). Если использовать `let`, то всплытия не будет, и по сути на каждой итерации цикла будет создаваться новая переменная. Однако, во-первых, это не влияет на производительность (даже в С — компилятор умный), и во-вторых, объявляя переменную внутри цикла, вы ограничиваете её область видимости. Почему это хорошо — отдельный вопрос.

Comment: То есть, если переменная "a" уже создана, то "var a;" ничего не делает?

Comment: Ок, ладно, влиять на производительность может (особенно в C++ если конструктор/деструктор делает какую-то "тяжёлую" работу), но для тривиальных типов вроде `int` проблем быть не должно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отличие от let и const, var не имеет блочной области видимости, поэтому в вашем случае будет использоваться одна и та же переменная. Можно проверить, сравнив вывод:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = i;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let a;
  console.log(a);
  a = i;
}
```

Comment: То есть, если переменная "a" уже создана, то "var a;" ничего не делает?

Comment: Если эта переменная передекларируется в границах одной функции или в верхней области видимости, то да. В JS лучше вообще не использовать сейчас var именно потому, что она имеет подобные причуды и с ней легко ошибиться, особенно если есть привычка к блочной области видимости из других языков.